# Excel VBA looping through select worksheets

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to write a Macro that will loop through select amount of worksheets to hide empty rows on each sheet. In column "A" on each worksheet contains a 1 or a 0. If it's a 0 I want to hide the row.

Here's my code that I've scrapped together from various websites. My biggest challenge is knowing which objects I need to manipulate.

```
enter code here
Public Sub HideRows()
Dim beginRow As Double
Dim endRow As Double
Dim ChkCol As Double
Dim RowCnt As Double
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim ArrayOne As Variant
Dim InxW As Long

beginRow = 10
endRow = 185
ChkCol = 1

ArrayOne = Array("GB", "Adj. B", "Adj. F", "JC-Results", "PI-Results", "MK-Results", "TD-Results")


For InxW = LBound(ArrayOne) To UBound(ArrayOne)
    For RowCnt = beginRow To endRow
    If Cells(RowCnt, ChkCol).Value = 0 Then
        Cells(RowCnt, ChkCol).EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Else
        Cells(RowCnt, ChkCol).EntireRow.Hidden = False
    End If
    Next RowCnt

Next



End Sub
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
Public Sub HideRows()
Dim beginRow As Double
Dim endRow As Double
Dim ChkCol As Double
Dim RowCnt As Double
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim ArrayOne As Variant
Dim InxW As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

beginRow = 10
endRow = 185
ChkCol = 1

ArrayOne = Array("GB", "Adj. B", "Adj. F", "JC-Results", "PI-Results", "MK-Results", "TD-Results")


For InxW = LBound(ArrayOne) To UBound(ArrayOne)
    With Sheets(ArrayOne(InxW))
        For RowCnt = beginRow To endRow
            If .Cells(RowCnt, ChkCol).Value = 0 Then
                .Rows(RowCnt).Hidden = True
            Else
                .Rows(RowCnt).Hidden = False
            End If
        Next RowCnt
    End With

Next InxW

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub
```

The main issue is that you are not telling Excel which sheet to search so it is searching only the active sheet as of the start of the code.

By putting everything in a `With` block and using the `.` in front of all range objects will tell excel which sheet to use.

Also turning of the calculations, screen updating and events off will help speed up the code, because it will not pause to do those things.

Comment: Is there a term for using `.` when using `With`? I've always wondered what it's referred to when you use the decimal as a "placeholder" for the `With [whatever]`.

Comment: @BruceWayne As I was typing the explanation, I wondered the same.

Comment: Hmm, I'm just going to start saying "you need to anchor your `With` statement with a period."  That sounds okay, eh?

Comment: @BruceWayne - perhaps *'assign parentage to the object referenced in the [With ... End With statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc500chb.aspx)'* ...?

Comment: @ScottCraner Thank you so much that worked! Starting to learn VBA, looks like I have a lot to learn!

Comment: @Bruce Glad to help, please mark as correct by hitting the green check mark by the answer, it will mark this as being solved and remove it from the unanswered list.

Answer (score 1):

The [AutoFilter method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa221844.aspx) would make quick work of this. Opting to hide the dropdowns will closely mimic hiding the rows as well as addding additional methods of unhiding them.

```
Public Sub HideRows()
    Dim beginRow As Long, endRow As Long, chkCol As Long
    Dim ndx As Long, arrOne As Variant

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    beginRow = 10
    endRow = 185
    chkCol = 1
    arrOne = Array("sheet1", "GB", "Adj. B", "Adj. F", "JC-Results", _
                     "PI-Results", "MK-Results", "TD-Results")

    For ndx = LBound(arrOne) To UBound(arrOne)
        With Worksheets(arrOne(ndx))
            If .AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilterMode = False
            With .Cells(beginRow - 1, chkCol).Resize(endRow - beginRow + 2, 1)
                .Columns(1).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>0", _
                                            VisibleDropDown:=False
                Debug.Print .Address
            End With
        End With
    Next ndx

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

There was no discussion on blanks but that could easily be added to Criteria2 with an [XlAutoFilterOperator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839625.aspx) of **xlOr**.