# Delete rows not equal to combobox value?

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to delete rows that are not equal to a combobox value that is selected. I have the following code, but i get a run-time error 424 Object required. Can anyone assist?

```
Dim wkss As Worksheet, wkJob As Worksheet
Dim i As Long
Set wkss = Sheets("TempWs6")
Set wsJob = Sheets("Job")

wkss.Select

For i = Cells(Rows.Count, 10).End(xlUp).Row To 1 Step -1
    If Cells(i, 10) <> wsJob.ComboBox1.Value Then
        wkss.Rows(i).Row.Delete
    End If
Next i
```

Thanks much!

Comment: Is the error occurring on the line with `wsJob.ComboBox1.Value`?

Comment: I modified code a little, but it occurs on "wkss.Rows(i).Row.Delete"

Comment: Try using `wkss.Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete`.

Comment: @BruceWayne - Can you make that an answer?

Answer (score 3):

To delete a row, you'd use `EntireRow`:

`wkss.Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete` should do it!

(For what it's worth, the same goes for removing an entire column, use `EntireColumn.Delete`)

Edit: Let's clear up the ranges and selections by [assigning parentage](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34934998/4650297) with a `With` statement.

```
Dim wkss As Worksheet, wkJob As Worksheet
Dim i As Long
Set wkss = Sheets("TempWs6")
Set wsJob = Sheets("Job")

With wkss

For i = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 10).End(xlUp).Row To 1 Step -1
    If .Cells(i, 10) <> wsJob.ComboBox1.Value Then
        .Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
    End If
Next i
End With
```

The `.Cells([...]).Row to 1 Step -1` does this:  Starting at your last row (which you get from `...(xlUp).Row`), run the code below, then "step" up one row, and run again, and repeat until you reach row `1`.

Comment: @ScottCraner - Ah, yeah. That's right - I was just thinking he'd like to see the extra descriptor (`EntireRow`) so kept that there.

Comment: i'm getting an error Run-Time error '1004' Delete method of Range class failed. It deletes the rows I need but then give that error on line wkss.Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete. Any ideas?

Comment: Just wanted to add that the OP was referencing the *row number* as an integer, not the actual worksheet row as a [Range object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838238.aspx). The [Range.Row](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196952.aspx) is a **property** that returns the row number.

Comment: @Chris2015 what is the value of i when it stops?

Comment: Can you explain what To 1 Step -1 means. I am still seeing 1 row remaining that doesn't meet my condition

Comment: bruce, you may want to do the whole code and qualify all the `Cells` objects.  I think it may be what is throwing the errors.

Comment: @ScottCraner - Good call, and it's one of my favorite things to do/teach :P.

Comment: Thanks everyone! Very helpful.