# Subscript out of range/ application defined or object defined error VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I asked a similar question a while ago and thought I had fixed my problem but for some reason I tried to run it later on and the same error popped up even though it was fine earlier. Anyway I either get a subscript out of range/ application defined or object defined error when I try and run this code. I am trying to find the cell in a sheet that has the words "current assets:". Here is my code. I feel like the problem is either in the 'range' that I am using 'find' on.

```
Sub Valuation()
   Dim LastRow As Long
        LastRow = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").SpecialCells(XlCellType.xlCellTypeLastCell).Row

   Dim LastColumn As Long
        LastColumn = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").SpecialCells(XlCellType.xlCellTypeLastCell).Column
   Dim crntassone As Range

   Set crntassone = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(LastRow, LastColumn)).Find(What:="Current assets:", After:=Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(1, 1)), LookIn:=xlValue, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)
```

If anyone sees the problem it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Which line of code is generating the error'

Answer (score 1):

I believe the issue is you aren't [assigning parentage](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34955091/4650297) to the `Cells()`.  Try replacing your line:

`Set crntassone = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(LastRow, LastColumn)).Find(What:="Current assets:", After:=Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(1, 1)), LookIn:=xlValue, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)`

With

```
With Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set crntassone = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(LastRow, LastColumn)).Find(What:="Current assets:", After:=.Range(.Cells(1, 1)), LookIn:=xlValue, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)
End With
```

I used `With` since it saves some space (notice the `.`s).  An alternative is to just add `Worksheets("Sheet1")` before any `Cells()` reference (also includes `Rows()`, `Columns()` if you used those).

If you don't assign parentage, you'll get an error unless the sheet you're trying to refer to is the ActiveSheet.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you need all that if you just use `Set crntassone = Cells.Find(What:="Current assets:", After:=[A1], SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False)`